# How to refer state in link on react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use a router like this:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/detail/:blogId" component={DetailView}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

and in `blog.js` I use `Link`

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/detail", query: { blogId: this.props.id } }}>Detail</Link>
```

but it didn't work, how to replace the `:blogId` part with state or props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:blogId` is a param, not a query.

You can simply set your param in the link tag like this:

```jsx
<Link to={'/detail/' + this.props.id}>Detail</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write
Var link= "detail/" + this.props.id;

Detail